# Count occurences of True/False in column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, counter, series

Is there a way to count the number of occurrences of boolean values in a column without having to loop through the DataFrame?

Doing something like

```
df[df["boolean_column"]==False]["boolean_column"].sum()
```

Will not work because False has a value of 0, hence a sum of zeroes will always return 0.

Obviously you could count the occurrences by looping over the column and checking, but I wanted to know if there's a pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'boolean_column': [True, False, True, False, True]})
>> df['boolean_column'].value_counts()
True     3
False    2
Name: boolean_column, dtype: int64
```

If you want to count `False` and `True` separately you can use `pd.Series.sum()` + `~`:

```
>> df['boolean_column'].values.sum()  # True
3
>> (~df['boolean_column']).values.sum() # False
2
```

Answer (score 10):

With Pandas, the natural way is using [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False, True, False, True]})

print(df['A'].value_counts())

# True     3
# False    2
# Name: A, dtype: int64
```

To calculate `True` or `False` values separately, don't compare against `True` / `False` explicitly, just `sum` and take the reverse Boolean via `~` to count `False` values:

```
print(df['A'].sum())     # 3
print((~df['A']).sum())  # 2
```

This works because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and the behaviour also holds true for Pandas series / NumPy arrays.

Alternatively, you can calculate counts using NumPy:

```
print(np.unique(df['A'], return_counts=True))

# (array([False,  True], dtype=bool), array([2, 3], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find here what I exactly need. I needed the number of True and False occurrences for further calculations, so I used:

```
true_count = (df['column']).value_counts()[True]
False_count = (df['column']).value_counts()[False]
```

Where df is your DataFrame and column is the column with booleans.

Comment: wasn't this easily extrapolated from the accepted answer?

Comment: This works but not always, if all the values are True or all the values are false it would raise a KeyError

Answer (score 2):

This alternative works for multiple columns and/or rows as well.

```
df[df==True].count(axis=0)
```

Will get you the total amount of `True` values per column. For row-wise count, set `axis=1`.

```
df[df==True].count().sum()
```

Adding a `sum()` in the end will get you the total amount in the entire DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply sum:

```
sum(df["boolean_column"])
```

This will find the number of "True" elements.

```
len(df["boolean_column"]) - sum(df["boolean_column"])
```

Will yield the number of "False" elements.

Comment: Note it's not good practice to use built-ins with Pandas / NumPy objects. For vectorisation benefits, use `pd.Series.sum` or `np.ndarray.sum`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.isnull()
```

returns a boolean value. `True` indicates a missing value.

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

returns column wise sum of `True` values.

```
df.isnull().sum().sum()
```

returns total no of NA elements.

Comment: But OP doesn't want to count missing cells, but cells with boolean values in them...

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a column in a DataFrame with boolean values, or even more interesting, in case you do not have it but you want to find the number of values in a column satisfying a certain condition you can try something like this (as an example I used <=):

```
(df['col']<=value).value_counts()
```

the parenthesis create a tuple with # of True/False values which you can use for other calcs as well, accessing the tuple adding [0] for False counts and [1] for True counts even without creating an additional variable:

```
(df['col']<=value).value_counts()[0] #for falses
(df['col']<=value).value_counts()[1] #for trues
```

Comment: I used this way some time ago, but it is not a good approach. First, value_counts gives you the most abundant value/bin first and sorts descendingly. Thus, if you don't know, what is the most probable value, the first value might be not the "False". Second, if you have just one value, df.[whatever].value_counts()[1] will raise an error, because there is no such element. The approaches using .sum or .value.sum are more failsafe in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to be as literal and brief as possible in providing an answer.  The `value_counts()` strategies are probably more flexible at the end. Accumulation `sum` and counting `count` are different and each expressive of an analytical intent, `sum` being dependent on the type of data.

"Count occurences of True/False in column of dataframe"

```
import pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'boolean_column': [True, False, True, False, True]})

df[df==True].count()
#boolean_column    3
#dtype: int64

df[df!=False].count()
#boolean_column    3
#dtype: int64

df[df==False].count()
#boolean_column    2
#dtype: int64
```