# Count occurrences of False or True in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

given

```
patient_id  test_result has_cancer
0   79452   Negative    False
1   81667   Positive    True
2   76297   Negative    False
3   36593   Negative    False
4   53717   Negative    False
5   67134   Negative    False
6   40436   Negative    False
```

how to count False or True in a column , in  python?

I had been trying:

```
# number of patients with cancer

number_of_patients_with_cancer= (df["has_cancer"]==True).count()
print(number_of_patients_with_cancer)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurences of True/False in column of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415751/count-occurences-of-true-false-in-column-of-dataframe)

Answer (score 106):

So you need `value_counts` ?

```
df.col_name.value_counts()
Out[345]: 
False    6
True     1
Name: has_cancer, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks!! how do I print only "False"? (I'm checking https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html but is not really clear)

Comment: +1@NeyJTorres For the record, you can get just the `False` number by appending `.loc[False]`, as in `df.has_cancer.value_counts().loc[False]`.  However, when you only need *either* `True` or `False` (but not both), I think it's just easier to use coldspeed's approach of  something like `(~df.has_cancer).sum()`.

Answer (score 65):

If `has_cancer` has NaNs:

```
false_count = (~df.has_cancer).sum()
```

If `has_cancer` does not have NaNs, another option is to subtract from the length of the dataframe and avoid negation. Not necessarily better than the previous approach.

```
false_count = len(df) - df.has_cancer.sum()
```

And similarly, if you want *just* the count of True values, that is

```
true_count = df.has_cancer.sum()
```

If you want both, it is

```
fc, tc = df.has_cancer.value_counts().sort_index().tolist()
```

Comment: Are you sure the subtraction is an optimization?

Answer (score 16):

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
```

If the  panda series above is called example

```
example.sum()
```

Then this code outputs 1 since there is only one `True` value in the series. To get the count of `False`

```
len(example) - example.sum()
```

Answer (score 8):

```
number_of_patients_with_cancer = df.has_cancer[df.has_cancer==True].count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your above data frame as a df

```
True_Count = df[df.has_cancer == True]

len(True_Count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sum the column for a count of the Trues. False is just a special case of 0 and True a special case of 1. The False count would be your row count minus that. Unless you've got `na`'s in there.

Comment: and if I do have NaN in there?

Comment: `na`'s sum as if they were `0`, last I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Count `True`:

```py
df["has_cancer"].sum()
```

Count `False`:

```py
(~df["has_cancer"]).sum()
```

See [Boolean operators](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-operators).