# pandas - column that counts the number of true in a series of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that describes whether work sites have tools. It has a simple true/false for describing if the tool is present. Unfortunately, the tool names are not standardized but I do have a list of them.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Index |  County | State | JDKFK | YSAFQ | MDFKN |
+-------+----_----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     0 | '001'   | '05'  | TRUE  | TRUE  | TRUE  |
|     1 | '030'   | '05'  | FALSE | TRUE  | FALSE |
|     2 | '005'   | '05'  | TRUE  | TRUE  | FALSE |
+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Using my list, how can I produce a new column that has the sum of TRUE in the specified columns?

`cols = ['JDKFK ', 'YSAFQ ', 'MDFKN ']`

```
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
| Index | County | State | JDKFK | YSAFQ | MDFKN | Tool_Sum |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
|     0 | '01'   | '05'  | TRUE  | TRUE  | TRUE  |        3 |
|     1 | '01'   | '05'  | FALSE | TRUE  | FALSE |        1 |
|     2 | '01'   | '05'  | TRUE  | TRUE  | FALSE |        2 |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+
```

[Count occurrences of False or True in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550988/count-occurrences-of-false-or-true-in-a-column-in-pandas) does not answer my question because that post defines how to count True/False in a single column (vertical) whereas my question is how to count True/False across multiple columns (horizontal).

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of False or True in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550988/count-occurrences-of-false-or-true-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df['tool_sum'] = df[['JDKFK', 'YSAFQ', 'MDFKN']].sum(1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Index County State  JDKFK  YSAFQ  MDFKN  tool_sum
0      0   '01'  '05'   True   True   True         3
1      1   '01'  '05'  False   True  False         1
2      2   '01'  '05'   True   True  False         2
```

The `sum(1)` means that is going to sum across the second axis (i.e `1` because it counts from `0`). Another way to see it sum across columns.

Comment: Can you please explain the 1 in sum()?