# Count showing up as NaN

Tags: python

I'm on the last step of finishing my table, but my count is returning NaN. I'm trying to create a column target_days which groups by each value in 'month_start_date' and returns the value of the count of workday if True.

For example, each date that has a month_start_date of 2018-08-01 should return a value of 23 because there are 23 workdays in that month. Any help is appreciated!

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as holidaylist

datelist = pd.date_range(start='2018-08-01', end=dt.datetime.today())
weekdaylist = pd.date_range(start='2018-08-01', end=dt.datetime.today(), freq='B')
mstartlist = (datelist + dt.timedelta(1)) + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=-1)

hl = holidaylist()
holidays = hl.holidays(start=datelist.min(), end=datelist.max())

df = pd.DataFrame(datelist, columns = ['date'])

df['weekday'] = df.date.isin(weekdaylist)

df['holiday'] = df.date.isin(holidays)

df['workday'] = np.where((df.weekday == False) | (df.holiday == True), False, True)

df['month_start_date'] = mstartlist

df['target_days'] = df.groupby('month_start_date')['workday'].apply(lambda x: x[x == True].count())

          date  weekday  holiday  workday month_start_date  target_days
0   2018-08-01     True    False     True       2018-08-01          NaN
1   2018-08-02     True    False     True       2018-08-01          NaN
2   2018-08-03     True    False     True       2018-08-01          NaN
3   2018-08-04    False    False    False       2018-08-01          NaN
4   2018-08-05    False    False    False       2018-08-01          NaN
```

Comment: How about df['target_days'] = df.groupby('month_start_date')['workday'].value_count()`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550988/count-occurrences-of-false-or-true-in-a-column-in-pandas

Comment: I got an error "'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_count'" but then changed from value_count to value_counts, thinking it would resolve the issue, but then resulted in another error: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Comment: you have to change the index of your df and merge on the groupby
df.index = df["date"]
pd.concat([df, df_group], axis=1, join="outer")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with groupby() and .transform(). Based on the response in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200693/python-pandas-how-to-assign-groupby-operation-results-back-to-columns-in-parent),

```
"As a general rule when using groupby(), if you use the .transform() 
function pandas will return a table with the same length as your 
original. When you use other functions like .sum() or .first() then 
pandas will return a table where each row is a group."
```

With that as a way to move forward, I was able to get the right solution.

```
df['target_days'] = df.groupby('month_start_date')['workday'].transform('sum')
```

The output of this is correct. The sample for month 2021-01-01 shows:

```
          date  weekday  holiday  workday month_start_date  target_days
884 2021-01-01     True     True    False       2021-01-01            8
885 2021-01-02    False    False    False       2021-01-01            8
886 2021-01-03    False    False    False       2021-01-01            8
887 2021-01-04     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
888 2021-01-05     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
889 2021-01-06     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
890 2021-01-07     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
891 2021-01-08     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
892 2021-01-09    False    False    False       2021-01-01            8
893 2021-01-10    False    False    False       2021-01-01            8
894 2021-01-11     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
895 2021-01-12     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
896 2021-01-13     True    False     True       2021-01-01            8
```

The first 100 rows have correct value count for `holiday = True`:

```
          date  weekday  holiday  workday month_start_date  target_days
0   2018-08-01     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
1   2018-08-02     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
2   2018-08-03     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
3   2018-08-04    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
4   2018-08-05    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
5   2018-08-06     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
6   2018-08-07     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
7   2018-08-08     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
8   2018-08-09     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
9   2018-08-10     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
10  2018-08-11    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
11  2018-08-12    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
12  2018-08-13     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
13  2018-08-14     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
14  2018-08-15     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
15  2018-08-16     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
16  2018-08-17     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
17  2018-08-18    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
18  2018-08-19    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
19  2018-08-20     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
20  2018-08-21     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
21  2018-08-22     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
22  2018-08-23     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
23  2018-08-24     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
24  2018-08-25    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
25  2018-08-26    False    False    False       2018-08-01           23
26  2018-08-27     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
27  2018-08-28     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
28  2018-08-29     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
29  2018-08-30     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
30  2018-08-31     True    False     True       2018-08-01           23
31  2018-09-01    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
32  2018-09-02    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
33  2018-09-03     True     True    False       2018-09-01           19
34  2018-09-04     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
35  2018-09-05     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
36  2018-09-06     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
37  2018-09-07     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
38  2018-09-08    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
39  2018-09-09    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
40  2018-09-10     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
41  2018-09-11     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
42  2018-09-12     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
43  2018-09-13     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
44  2018-09-14     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
45  2018-09-15    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
46  2018-09-16    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
47  2018-09-17     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
48  2018-09-18     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
49  2018-09-19     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
50  2018-09-20     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
51  2018-09-21     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
52  2018-09-22    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
53  2018-09-23    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
54  2018-09-24     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
55  2018-09-25     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
56  2018-09-26     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
57  2018-09-27     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
58  2018-09-28     True    False     True       2018-09-01           19
59  2018-09-29    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
60  2018-09-30    False    False    False       2018-09-01           19
61  2018-10-01     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
62  2018-10-02     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
63  2018-10-03     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
64  2018-10-04     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
65  2018-10-05     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
66  2018-10-06    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
67  2018-10-07    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
68  2018-10-08     True     True    False       2018-10-01           22
69  2018-10-09     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
70  2018-10-10     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
71  2018-10-11     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
72  2018-10-12     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
73  2018-10-13    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
74  2018-10-14    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
75  2018-10-15     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
76  2018-10-16     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
77  2018-10-17     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
78  2018-10-18     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
79  2018-10-19     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
80  2018-10-20    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
81  2018-10-21    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
82  2018-10-22     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
83  2018-10-23     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
84  2018-10-24     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
85  2018-10-25     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
86  2018-10-26     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
87  2018-10-27    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
88  2018-10-28    False    False    False       2018-10-01           22
89  2018-10-29     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
90  2018-10-30     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
91  2018-10-31     True    False     True       2018-10-01           22
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, I am getting some challenges when I test this on python.org. I dont have my personal laptop to test. I will do some more tests tonight and let you know if there are any changes to be done.  Look at results for `2021-01-01` The answer is 8 while there are 9 True statements. Also the answer is 23 for False while there are only 5 False. This is the answer I get on the virtual vm. I will test it on my personal laptop later tonight

Comment: Almost there - it looks like the target days value is being placed into every row, instead of only if that row's workday = True, each month_start_date should have a different value. It looks like it's replicating the August 2018 results for all rows. Also, I'm using [0] because there should be 23 workdays for the month instead of 8 workdays.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there...

```
df.groupby('month_start_date')['workday'].apply(lambda x: x[x == True].count())
```

returns the count for unique `month_start_date` which has a size of `30`

```
2018-08-01    23
2018-09-01    19
2018-10-01    22
2018-11-01    20
2018-12-01    20
2019-01-01    21
2019-02-01    19
2019-03-01    21
2019-04-01    22
2019-05-01    22
2019-06-01    20
2019-07-01    22
2019-08-01    22
2019-09-01    20
2019-10-01    22
2019-11-01    19
2019-12-01    21
2020-01-01    21
2020-02-01    19
2020-03-01    22
2020-04-01    22
2020-05-01    20
2020-06-01    22
2020-07-01    22
2020-08-01    21
2020-09-01    21
2020-10-01    21
2020-11-01    19
2020-12-01    22
2021-01-01     9
Name: workday, dtype: int64
```

We need to merge these values basis the dates in the above obtained Series object with the `df['date']`

```
df['target_days'] = pd.merge(df[['date']], workdays_ss, how='left', left_on='date', right_index=True)['workday']

df
```

**Output:**

```
0   2018-08-01  True    False   True    2018-08-01  23.0
1   2018-08-02  True    False   True    2018-08-01  NaN
2   2018-08-03  True    False   True    2018-08-01  NaN
3   2018-08-04  False   False   False   2018-08-01  NaN
4   2018-08-05  False   False   False   2018-08-01  NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
893 2021-01-10  False   False   False   2021-01-01  NaN
894 2021-01-11  True    False   True    2021-01-01  NaN
895 2021-01-12  True    False   True    2021-01-01  NaN
896 2021-01-13  True    False   True    2021-01-01  NaN
897 2021-01-14  True    False   True    2021-01-01  NaN
```

It is showing `NaN` in `target_days` because it matches with the first day of every month (Try running `df[df['target_days'].notnull()]`).
You can tweak the logic if you want `target_date` populated for all the dates of a month.

Comment: Yup. pd.merge() was missing.