# Turning the True into a count of a columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I Have column "Counts" that has a true false count and I want to get just the counts of the True values

```
SubmitDate_NoTime ResolvedDate_NoTime         Count
0   2021-01-01  2021-01-03           0 True 1 True 2 True 3 Fals... 
1   2021-01-01  2021-01-02           0 True 1 True 2 True 3 Fals... 
2   2021-01-01  2021-01-06           0 True 1 True 2 True 3 Fals..
```

This is an example of one row list each row has a list similar to this.

```
 0      True
 1      True
 2      True
 3     False
 4     False
 5     False
 6     False
 7     False
 8     False
 9     False
 10    False
 11    False
 12    False
 13    False
 14    False
 15    False
 16    False
 17    False
 18    False
 19    False
 20    False
```

I have tried

```
 df['Counts'] = tickets['Counts'].sum()
 df['Counts'] = df[df['Counts']==True].count().sum()
```

Neither have worked

I want the df to look like df['Counts'][1] = 3
in this case.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550988/count-occurrences-of-false-or-true-in-a-column-in-pandas

Comment: Yes, those suggestions dont work for me because in a single row under the count column there is a list of many true or falses and I need the count of them.

Comment: they suggest using the sum feature which I have tried and it does not give me a count

Comment: what is the output of `print(type(df.Counts.iloc[0]))`